# bitcoin-cli getbalance 0 after restart

Tags: bitcoind

I am working on a private chain using regtest mode. I have a strange behaviour if i restart the bitcoind process the balance becomes 0.?

i generate 101 new block to get the reward 50BTC. I repeat this operation to be sure but always i get the same result the balance is 0.

```
before 
C:\WINDOWS\system32>bitcoin-cli -regtest getbalance
8800.00000000
after
C:\WINDOWS\system32>bitcoin-cli -regtest getbalance
0.00000000
```

update : the problem was the use of CTRL+C to stop the bitcoind deamon

Comment: Can you please update your post and show us the commands you use to start and restart bitcoind in regtest mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably haven't gracefully shutdown your node during the first run.

Make sure you always stop your node(s) with `./bitcoin-cli -regtest stop`